# express json object in highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, highcharts, pug

I am trying to populate a highchart in jade(with javascript) with JSON data send from node.js. I do this by adding JavaScript in jade, this works fine with static data as shown below:

```
var series =  [  
  {  
  name: 'Tokyo',  
  data: [7.0]  
  }
];
```

Now I want to add JSON data from node.js. I implemented the following:

```
app.get('/chart', function(req,res){
var chartData = [
  {
  name: 'Tokyo',
  data: [7.0]
  }
  ];
  res.render('chart', {
    chart: chartData
  });
});
```

When I print chartData in console, the output is the same as the static data. When I set(in jade)
`var series = '#{chart}'` I get an empty highchart.

The problem seems to be the JSON from node js. Highcharts gives as many series as there are characters, which means jade/javascript is not parsing the JSON correctly, but character by character instead(each character is new object). I have printed `chartData` from node.js to my console, showing the following:

```
[ { name: 'Tokyo', data: [ 7 ] } ]
```

I have tried `JSON.stringify` in my node js file, but this returns invalid JSON as follows:

```
var series = '[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Tokyo&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[7]}]';
```

How can I get my chart to work with the JSON returned from node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve this. In node js:

```
var chartData = [];  
chartData.push({
          name: 'Tokyo'
          data: [7.0]
});

res.render('chart', {
  chart: chartData
});
```

My mistake was in Javascript within Jade, when parsing the JSON. Following solved the problem:

`!{JSON.stringify(chart)}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble outputting proper JSON, try the `JSON.stringify` method.

```
app.get('/chart', function(req,res){
var chartData = [
  {
  name: 'Tokyo',
  data: [7.0]
  }
  ];
  res.render('chart', {
    chart: JSON.stringify(chartData, null, 4)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I have tried this and I get the output from my question, single last sentence.

Comment: Just do a res.json or res.send with only the json object then

Comment: Interesting approach. How can I render my jade page when sending res.json?

Comment: My approach is based on making an asyc call once your page is loaded.  If you're wanting to render the data server side that's a whole different approach